# Where to "host" a Progressive Web App (PWA)?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Im just starting out diving into PWAs. 
Where should a PWA being published?

Can it be published like any other javascript app on the web (as a simple URL)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A PWA is like any other website.   You can host it anywhere you can host a "regular" site, as long as it is served via HTTPS.

Comment: It must be HTTPS? What happens if it's HTTP?

Comment: Then it isn't a PWA.  This is one of the requirements of being a PWA.

Answer (score 2):

A PWA is made up of service workers, which can run in the background. To avoid tampering with service workers the specification of PWA requires it to be hosted over HTTPS.

So any hosts supporting HTTPS would be good enough for them.